# Отправка данных из Google Forms в метод программы на c#

Tags: c#

Появилась необходимость получать ответы из Google Forms, затем обрабатывать их на c#. В программе есть WebApi.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать эту информацию. Возможно можно как-то через таблицу брать значение при его обновлении или что-то подобное.

Comment: [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet) - полагаю, вам нужно это..

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov SheetsAPI - это для гугл таблиц, для форм скорее всего подойдёт [Google.Apis.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Forms.v1)